# How to summarise recent changes in a OneNote notebook?

Tags: version-control, microsoft-onenote

I know that OneNote keeps a history for each page in a notebook and that I can access this history for each individual page, but is there any way to get a change log *for the entire notebook*?

For context, we use OneNote at work to record our ISO9001 quality management system. We've got an audit coming up and I'd like to be able to:

1. quickly demonstrate that it's actively being maintained
2. show what changes have been made since the last audit

Even if the solution is a 3rd party tool, I'd settle for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out I was missing something really obvious. On the **Share** tab, simply click the **Recent Edits** button and select one of the timescale options in the menu that appears:

[image: The Recent Edits button on the Share tab]

Simple.

Comment: nowadays this ribbon menu has been renamed to **History**